# fire function only when certain zoom levels are present

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to fire a couple of functions after certain zoom levels are met on my Google Map.  Below is probably not close to being right but I'm hoping it can give everyone an idea.  I'm pretty sure you'll use a zoom_changed actionlistener but I'm pretty clueless after that.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    map.Zoom(zoomLoad, 4);
});

function zoomLoad() {
    getFishing();
    getLaunches();
}
```

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be awesome.

Comment: What is map.Zoom?  You can't just make up functions and expect anything to happen (other than errors in the javascript console).

Comment: I know it was wrong, I was just giving an example of how I thought it would be setup.

Comment: @HondaKillrsx: Please make that visible *while* asking the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. use the zoom_changed event on the map
2. when that fires, get the current zoom level ([map.getZoom()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map))
3. perform what ever action it is you want to do based on the current zoom level

[The documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events) has some discussion of this and [an example](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-properties)

---

> *HondaKillrsx:* I got it working for my code, which is below:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
var zoomLevel = map.getZoom();

if (zoomLevel > 7) {
  getLaunches();
  getFishing();
}
else {
  clearLaunches();
  clearFishing();
}
```

Comment: Got it! Thank you.  I updated the code with how I am using it.